# CPU spikes / almost 100% used even with very simple request and response in ASP.NET Core 6/7 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

Scenario as below:

1. We have very simple rest api developed in node.js (Express) that reads data from Redis and return response, working fine with huge load and mostly CPU spikes are under control even with huge load
2. We have decided to port the node.js api into .NET Core as rest all component of the project in .NET Core but we found that same load which was served in node is being served with double resources in .NET Core just because of CPU usages very high and we are using AWS autoscaling so new host get added very soon or we can say even with half of the load of the node.js web api so just wanted to solve this issues hence I captured the .NET traces from the server to analyze the CPU usages.
3. We are using `StackExchange.Redis` to connect with Redis server from ASP.NET Core
4. We are using `ConnectionMultiplexer` as a singleton instance so only one connection to Redis throughout the application
5. .NET trace analysis result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `using AWS autoscaling` -> going to AWS support team to ask for help seems to be a good idea... not sure if AWS had support team or not. You need to know is it an expected behavior for asp.net core api. narrow down the issue then investigate it.

Comment: @TinyWang AWS auto-scaling I just added for scenario explanation  only here aws playing no role in CPU bottleneck.

Comment: yes I know it. normally speaking, when we want to figure out why the server had a high CPU behavior, we usually need to make sure what the app was doing that time, so a `memory dump` will help. then we can find clues e.g. some line of code is costing much CPU. then for example you can ask here, my code xxxx worked well in node.js, but when I change the code to match .net core grammar, it cost much more CPU.... Then if you know how to analyse dump file, it's ok, if not, you may go to the cloud service provider to help...

Comment: @TinyWang In both cases .net core and node.js memory utilization of the server is quite normal the only issue is with CPU spikes in case of .net core and we are using StackExchange.Redis DLL for Redis data access which internally is using  the lib Sockets.Unofficial  (Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial.dedicatedThreadPoolPipeScheduler.RunWorkLoop()) which is consuming most of the CPU as highlighted in dotnet-trace analysis above.

Comment: then we can only pray someone else had similar issue with yours and share their ideas..

Comment: What version of StackExchange.Redis are you running?

Comment: @ChadT I am using StackExchange.Redis (2.6.80)

Comment: Hi i am having the same problem. When I do dotnet-trace collect, I always see 100% load, while the "top" command shows that this is not the case. I also have StackExchange.Redis, but the spikes are more focused on MongoDB.Driver